# Is there a way to define a preprocessor macro that includes preprocessor directives?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, pragma, preprocessor-directive

There are a few loops I would like to direct the compiler to unroll with code like below.  It is quite long and I'd rather not copy-paste.

Can #define statements define preprocessor macros?

I tried this:

```c
#define foo \
    #ifdef __GNUC__                                             \
        #if __GNUC__ >= 8                                       \
            #pragma GCC unroll 128                              \
            #pragma GCC ivdep                                   \
        #endif                                                  \
    #endif                                                      \
    #ifdef __clang__                                            \
        #pragma clang loop vectorize(enable) interleave(enable) \
    #endif
```

but when I use `foo` in the code `cpp` shows that it expands invalidly as:

```c
 #ifdef 4 #if 4 >= 8 #pragma GCC unroll 128 #pragma GCC ivdep #endif #endif #ifdef __clang__ #pragma clang loop vectorize(enable) interleave(enable) #endif
 #ifdef 4 #if 4 >= 8 #pragma GCC unroll 128 #pragma GCC ivdep #endif #endif #ifdef __clang__ #pragma clang loop vectorize(enable) interleave(enable) #endif
```

Comment: #define is, by definition, defining a preprocessor macro. That's not what you're trying to do. You're trying to express preprocessor *directives*. One could easily argue what you're trying to do is entirely inside-out of how it what you seem to be trying is normally done.

Comment: @WhozCraig, how is this normally done?

Comment: If you're married to gcc, you could do it as chqrlie has shown in his answer. Alternatively, you could pull your logic inside out and use a `#include` mechanic. Personally, I'd prefer chqrlie's way if the gnu restriction isn't a problem.

Comment: The C standard says "No" — see [§6.10.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement ¶3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3.4p3): _The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one, but all pragma unary operator expressions within it are then processed as specified in 6.10.9 below._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot define preprocessing directives the way you show in the question.

Yet you may be able to use the `_Pragma` operator for your purpose:

```
#if defined __GNUC__ && __GNUC__ >= 8
    #define foo _Pragma("GCC unroll 128") _Pragma("GCC ivdep")
#elif defined __clang__
    #define foo _Pragma("clang loop vectorize(enable) interleave(enable)")
#else
    #define foo
#endif
```